# How to add external jQuery for a particular div only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know that how to add external jQuery for a particular div only.

In my Project I have added a jQuery library in header section. But it will reflect the whole project.

But I want to reflect only for singe div. If you have any idea please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
  xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter"
  xmlns:j="tapestry-library:jquery">
<head>
<title>${message:index_title}</title>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="oeiNXBU5Fev7Pbt0353wKX5SiWfiWtQGdILNY5bRqHA" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="${context:layout/images/App_icon.png}" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${context:layout/css/style.css}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<style>
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; height:100px;}
div#slider figure { 
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 0;
animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
$("#first_one").on("swipe",function(){
    $(this).hide();
});                       
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider" style="height:100px; width:100%; padding:0px;
 margin:0px;">
    <figure id="first">
        <div id="first_one"><img src="${context:layout/images/top1.jpg}" 
          /></div></figure>
    <figure id="second">
        <img src="${context:layout/images/top2.jpg}" /></figure>
    <figure id="third">
        <img src="${context:layout/images/top5.jpg}" /></figure>
</div>  
<div id="category">
    <div id="category_header">
        <div id="category_style">All Videos</div>
    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <t:form t:id="searching">
            <div id="search_field"><input t:type="textfield"  
     t:id="search" placeholder="Search Video" size="20"/></div>
            <div id="search_button"><input t:type="submit" 
     t:id="searchSubmit" value="Search"/></div>
        </t:form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question does not make any sense.

Comment: jQuery is just a library, it doesn't do anything when you load it. Your Javascript can use it to affect any part of the DOM that it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Give your div an ID.

```
<div id='fart'>some stuff</div><
```

Then, in javascript, $("#fart").html("smell")

"#" references the ID of the element.  "." references the class.